# Zend Db Table Double JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, join

```
1. plan_payment_type:
   id
   plan_id

2. plan
   id
   payment_period
```

It is Foreign key between `plan_payment_type.plan_id` and `plan.id`. In my code I know a $plan_payment_type_id.

My task is to select `payment_period`.
Steps:

- Select `plan_id` from `plan_payment_type`
- Select `payment_period from` `plan` with selected `plan_id`

How can I do it with one query in Zend Framework?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following SQL statement and PHP code correspond to each other:

```
SELECT
  t.id AS plan_payment_type_id,
  p.id AS plan_id,
  p.payment_period
FROM
  plan_payment_type AS t
  INNER JOIN plan AS p ON p.id = t.plan_id
WHERE
  p.id = { SQL query param for $plan_payment_type_id }


$select = $db->select()
          ->from(array('t' => 'plan_payment_type'),
                 array('id' => 'plan_payment_type_id'))
          ->join(array('p' => 'plan'), 'p.id = t.plan_id',
                 array('id' => 'plan_id', 'payment_period'))
          ->where('p.id = ?', $plan_payment_type_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Before everything I would organize them differently. Is not the plan_types that should have a plan.id. This is not logical. You hava a table with plan_types which has an plan.id and a plan.name and the relation is in the plan table through the plan.type_id.

This [dependencies](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html) are solved this way:

```
class Payment_Plan extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name            = 'plan';
    protected $_referenceMap    = array(
        'Plan' => array(
            'columns'           => 'plan_id',
            'refTableClass'     => 'Plan',
            'refColumns'        => 'id'
        )

}

class Plan_Type extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name            = 'plan_types';
    protected $_dependentTables = array('Plan_Type');
}
```

Later you can have in the PlanRow Class a function :

```
public function type() {
    return $this->findParentRow('Plan_Type');
}
```

and for getting all the plans of type x in the Plan_type row class

```
public function entries() {
    return $row->findDependentRowset('Plan');
}
```

Comment: `Tomalak` answer is better for me. Thanks, `Elzo Valugi`.

Comment: +1 because you are right with regard to DB layout. Having a `plan_id` on `plan_payment_type` makes no sense to me either.

Comment: i think you are missing a ')' in your $_referenceMap variable